# Document type not defined in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, office365, document

I'm following this [mail merge](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MergeWithAttachments.htm) work that I found in a [related Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656091/add-cc-and-bcc-with-mail-merge) which looks to do something similar to what I'd like but I'm having trouble getting started.  I"ve narrowed the problem down to the below...

```
Sub TestEmailer()
    Dim Source As Document, Maillist As Document, TempDoc As Document
End Sub
```

With the error "User-defined type not defined."

It appears I'm missing a reference, but the reference recommended "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" doesn't seem to fix the issue when I enable it.

Has this Document object moved to a different library?  How do I find the right library in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this in Excel, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` and then use:

```
Sub TestEmailer()
    Dim Source As Word.Document, Maillist As Word.Document, TempDoc As Word.Document
End Sub
```

Each application will only load it's own objects by default, along with other common Office objects. If you want to use other objects from another application you either need to add a reference to that application's object library or use late binding.

In this instance I'd recommend early binding (adding a reference manually) so that you get the benefit of IntelliSense in your code, this will make it easier working across applications.

Comment: This works thanks.  Quick question though.  What do you mean by adding the reference manually?  This is my first VBA project.

Comment: Early binding vs Late binding. It's a whole subject to itself so best to google it. TL;DR = early binding requires you to go through Tools->References and add the library yourself at design time. Late binding is a way of creating objects in code that automatically find and reference the required library at compile time.